# extjs combobox afterrender() called together leading to asynchronous ajax calls

Tags: java, extjs

I'm developing an application using Java Spring and ExtJS. The front end contains a panel with some fields including 3 comboboxes. To fill the comboboxes, I have defined a function which is fired on ComboBox afterRender. I have a store for each combobox (each combobox is filled from different tables).

The problem is when the page is rendered, the function is called 3 times but only the 3rd combo box is filled, or the JSON string returned contains only the value for last combo box. Actually the request for all 3 comboboxes are sent, but only the last request is processed.

Can anyone give me an idea how to handle this problem?

This is how i defied a combo box.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    x: 300,
    y: 70,
    store: 'TasksStr',
    msgTarget: 'side',
    displayField: 'label',
    valueField: "value",
    itemId: 'TaskRef',                                  
    fieldLabel: 'Task Ref',
    name: 'taskRef'
} //Similarly 2 more combo boxes for Project and Status
```

This is the controller:

```
init: function(application) {              
    this.control({
        "#TaskRef": {
            afterrender: this.onComboboxAfterRender,
            select: this.onFormBlur                
        },
        "#ProjectRef": {
                afterrender: this.onComboboxAfterRender,
                select: this.onFormBlur                
        },
        "#StatusRef": {
            afterrender: this.onComboboxAfterRender,
            select: this.onFormBlur                
        }
    });
 }
```

This is the store:

```
Ext.define('MainApp.store.TasksStr', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MainApp.model.Model'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'TasksStr',
            model: 'MainApp.model.Model',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/project/Tasks',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'count'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

This is the controller in java:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}")
public String getElanLUT(@PathVariable("id") String Id, ModelMap model ){
    System.out.println(Id);
    try{
        ABCDao.set(Id);
        List<ABC> List = Dao.getABC();
        model.addAttribute("data", List);
        model.addAttribute("success", true);
        model.addAttribute("count", List.size());
    }catch(Exception e){
        model.addAttribute("success", false);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "jsonTemplate";
}
```

While running this code, the console for java prints all 3 Id's but the value returned is just the 3rd one.

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: A few questions, when you say the function is called three times are you referring to `Controler#onComboboxAfterRender` ?  How are the other comboboxes called (itemid), if you added the controller for `TaskRef` only, the method should only have been called one time. There is something wrong with the way you controller is setup.

Comment: TaskRef is just 1 combo box. I have 2 more combo boxes with respective itemid's. afterRender() is called simultaneously but only the last call is processed at back end.

Comment: But how is the afterRender being called three times if your Controller selector is just for `#TaskRef`?

Comment: Oh sorry, I haven't provided all the codes under controller. Actually there are 3 controller selectors in my machine. Example: 1.Task, 2.Project, 3:Status. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create store instances for all 3 combo boxes.

```
    {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        x: 300,
        y: 70,
        store: Ext.create('MainApp.store.TasksStr'),
        msgTarget: 'side',
        displayField: 'label',
        valueField: "value",
        itemId: 'TaskRef',                                  
        fieldLabel: 'Task Ref',
        name: 'taskRef'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But i have individual stores for them.